# Juery Ui & Autocomplete error

Tags: magento2, jquery

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
```

I am getting this error when I load the page.
This is the script i have written

```
    var stateArr = <?php echo json_encode($_stateArr)?>;
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage",
    "mage/validation"
], function($){
    jQuery( function() {
        document.getElementById('project').elements[i];
        var availableTags = stateArr;
        document.getElementById(postcode).autocomplete({
        //jQuery( "#postcode" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength:3
        });
    });
    $(".ui-autocomplete").appendTo($("#input-postcode-container"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> In require Define **`jquery/ui`** :-

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage",
    "mage/validation",
    "jquery/ui"
```

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below code:

```
var stateArr = <?php echo json_encode($_stateArr)?>;
require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/mage",
    "mage/validation"
], function($){
    jQuery( function() {
        document.getElementById('project').elements[i];
        var availableTags = stateArr;
        document.getElementById(postcode).autocomplete({
        //jQuery( "#postcode" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength:3
        });
    });
    $(".ui-autocomplete").appendTo($("#input-postcode-container"));
});
```

Check this for more reference : [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html)

Comment: still the same error